# $("#highcharts-2i5ujpv-2").highcharts() is undefined

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, highcharts-ng, angular2-highcharts

I have an AngularJS application in which I am using highcharts-ng version 0.0.86. I am generating the highchart by the following code

```
<highchart config="highchartsNg"></highchart>
```

The chart gets properly generated with this dynamic id "highcharts-2i5ujpv-2"

But whenever I type `$("#highcharts-2i5ujpv-2").highcharts()` in the browser console, it gives me `undefined`.

Also, I have other charts in my app for which I am creating the chart using jQuery inside a div container and it works fine. eg

```
<div id="multi-chart-container"></div>
$("#multi-chart-container").highcharts(chartconfig);
```

I need to understand why I does it give me undefined in the first case

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highcharts creates it's own `div` element with dynamic id. You need to get one level higher to get the chart:

```
$("#highcharts-2i5ujpv-2").parent().highcharts()
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5eq6yhg3/